# Как отследить проблемы с соединением к базе данных в Spring-boot приложении

Tags: java, база-данных, spring-boot

В моем десктопном приложении есть несколько соединений к базам данных. Если нет соединения с основной базой данных, то работа приложения не имеет смысла.

Есть ли способ отследить сбои соединения и уведомить об этом пользователя в Spring-boot приложении?

Я пробовал такое решение

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            Application.launch(args);
        } catch (java.net.ConnectException e) {
            //Уведомление пользователя
        }
}
```

Но в данном случае я не могу выявить базу данных с которой произошла проблема, т.к. stack trace не содержит никаких данных о соединении.

Как вариант можно по таймеру делать простой запрос, но этот подход требует большого количества бесполезных запросов.

Ну, и, конечно же, не вариант ловить исключение при каждом обращении к базе данных.

Comment: а что если вместо `//Уведомление пользователя` сделать `//Уведомление пользователя + проверка связи с главной БД`?

Comment: @tym32167 Да, как вариант можно и так. Спасибо за совет